# Write a computer program so that # heads/n diverges?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose a computer program  tosses a coin, and counts the times when it tosses 'head', denoted by $\#heads$.  Let $$X_n=\frac{\#~heads}{n}.$$ Is there a way to write the computer program so $X_n$ diverges?

Comment: Any restrictions on the random tosses? Specifically, what to you mean by random?

Comment: I think that for a fair coin $X_n$ will converge to 0.5 and $\frac{X_n}{n}$ to zero as $n \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Student001 I have remove 'random'. It is a computer program that tosses.

Comment: Define "diverges". It is often used to imply "goes to infinity". But $X_n/n$ cannot go off to infinity. Write your program so that it tosses only 1 until $X_n/n > 2/3$, then only 0 until $X_n/n < 1/3$ and continue in that way (where here $X_n$ is the cumulative number of 1's upto $n$.)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen what's wrong with 1/4 and 3/4? Less jokingly, $X_n/n$ is bounded above by $1/n$ with the OP's definition. It may be confusing do change definitions.

Comment: @whuber Tagging you since you are moderator. How is this question unclear? I suppose it's because some may instinctively think, as suggested above, "diverge" means approaches infinity. Indeed, that was my own gut reaction. But should we assume the OP does not know standard definitions just because some of us don't?

Comment: @Student001 I placed my vote to close after I read the comments, which show that even what a "toss" is has not been sufficiently well defined. If it's not random, then what is it?  What does the OP actually mean by "diverge"?  What, if anything, does this question even have to do with this site?

Comment: @whuber Ok, I see. I got the impression, from the comments, that it was the definition of divergence that caused confusion. My point is that there is a standard definition and that it's hardly the OP's responsibility to point out standard definitions. We don't, to take a contrived example, define the real numbers in every question involving them. Your other points make sense to me. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Student001 It may be worthwhile noticing that the confusion about the meaning of "diverges" was introduced by commenters and not by the OP.

Comment: @whuber I feel like we are perhaps talking past each other. What I meant was just that: the OP is being asked to clarify what he means by "diverge" even though there is, as far as I know, only one standard definition. Either way, I just wanted the rationale behind the voting and you have given me that. I'll have to get accumulate some points so that I may partake in the voting instad of writing long discussions in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

1. Toss Heads on first
2. Toss Tails until $X_n < 1/4$
3. Toss Heads until $X_n>3/4$
4. Repeat 2. and 3.

If you want some randomness in the algorithm, you may, e.g., let the tosses be Bernoulli with success probability $p<1/4$ in step 2. and $p>3/4$ in step 3. The strong law of large numbers ensures that $X_n$ will eventually be less than $1/4$ in step 2., and equivalently for step 3. Thus, the sequence $X_n$ will, with probability 1, be larger than 3/4 infinitely often and less than 1/2 infinitely often; it does not converge.

Comment: @zell you're welcome! If this answer is what you were looking for, consider updating the question to accommodate the requests in the comments.